# C# Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement C#

Tags: c#

```
if (txtUsername.Text != "")
        {
            string q = "insert into info(Username) values ('" + txtUsername.Text.ToString() + "')";
            dosomething(q);
            txtUsername.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Complete the neccessary information");
        }
        if (txtPassword.Text != "")
        {
            string a = "insert into info(Password) values ('" + txtPassword.Text.ToString() + "')";
            dosomething(a);
            txtUsername.Text = "";

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Complete the neccessary information");
        }

private void dosomething(String q)
{
    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = q;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        cn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Every time I run this it always show that error. I dont know how to fix it.
The code should record the data i put in a textbox to ms access database. plz helpp

Comment: where have you define cn & how did you pass the connectionstring to it?

Comment: please include the code of the connection string in your post

Comment: cn = connection object, which you would pass the connectionstring to... read up http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Comment: I know that this is a beginner's code, but there are just so many things wrong with that...

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you've initialized cn somewhere by doing something like

```
cn = new SqlConnection();
```

You need to pass the connection string for the database to the constructor:

```
cn = new SqlConnection("your connection string here");
```

or set it sometime later, before you connect:

```
cn.ConnectionString = "your connection string here";
```